# MySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) Timeout

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout

I'm having a trouble with the MySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) method.

Obviously, I'm using MySQL.

That problem started yesterday, before this, all went ok. This problem "came from nowhere".

I have a table that contains ~300 rows. And it will be much greater. When I do a query using the Fill method, it takes too much time to fetch the rows. And throws a Timeout exception.

It tooks ~30 seconds to fetch sucessfully only **80** rows!

**But** when I do the **SAME** query directly in the MySQL Query Browser, all the rows are fetched instantly.

I've tested the same method 2 days ago, and all went OK.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please include the offending SQL. Also, has anything else changed regarding network/server configurations?

Comment: hello, add stopwatch to know how many time take your Fill method

Comment: Nothing changed in the server configurations. Sorry, but I cant post the SQL, company policies. But I can say that the SQL has 3 inner joins and some filters. But when I query the same SQL in MySQL Query Browser, it tooks 0,02 seconds. Why?

Comment: I do not think a Stopwatch is necessary in this case,  because 80 rows is a very small number of rows to take longer than 1 second to fetch.

Comment: @RicardoPieper As Microsoft's help desk would say before anything else, have you rebooted your machine yet? :D

Comment: @Mike No, and I don't understand how this would solve my problem. If I can do a query in MySQL Query Browser quickly, why not in c #?
I'll restart the MySql Server, if this solves my problem, the server or the code is owned by the devil.

Comment: I've rebooted and a portuguese error appeared. It basically says "Timeout" D:

Comment: @RicardoPieper You just rebooted the service though right? Not the server? You know, I'm only saying this because I've seen this with Microsoft SQL Server as well. I had a SQL Server in a data center that I had to reboot daily. Now the queries would execute with satisfaction from Query Analyzer but terrible performance via the .NET adapters.

Comment: I solved the problem! I'll answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem!

Some days ago, I configured my app.config to do some tracing in my application, but I forgot to delete. I've put this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />

  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">

      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Cache">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add
     name="System.Net"
     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
            />
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I deleted it, recompiled and problem solved :D